# Image map / custom shaped clickable regions in WPF - WP7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-7

I am trying to replicate a remote like directional interface in WPF on Windows Phone 7 - basically a "select" circle within another circle which four arrows. How can I define the clickable areas since they are not normal shapes? My only idea is something like an an overlay of squares in a plus arrangement, though a pie shaped wedge in each corner won't be live

Comment: paths look like the best way, but I already did it the easy way based on this - see if anyone has issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose your graphics from [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615632%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) objects. These are hit-testable only in their drawn/filled parts.